# undefined method `offset' for an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am using the following step in my pagination method steps:

Edit : nodes2 is an array.

```
nodes = nodes2.take(per_page).offset((page_number.to_i - 1) * per_page)
@length = (nodes2.count/per_page).ceil
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method 'offset' for #<Array:0x00000005905128>
```

Basically I am using the following steps and they work fine as I get the objects out of .leaves method, but am not sure how to deal with the array

```
nodes = inode.leaves.limit(per_page).offset((page_number.to_i - 1) * per_page)
@length = (inode.leaves.count/per_page).ceil
```

Could some one pls help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`take` is a method on `Array`. When you run it against `nodes2` (which I assume is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object), it's doing the equivalent of this:

```
nodes = nodes2.to_a.take(per_page)...
```

So because of this, `offset` is being run on an Array object. You could try making `take(...)` be the last method call, that way `offset` is still being run against ActiveRecord:

```
nodes = nodes2.offset((page_number.to_i - 1) * per_page).take(per_page)
```

Comment: nodes2 is an array, Array#take returns an array, and there is no Array#offset method (which is what you are trying to call). This is what the error is telling you.

Comment: @looby ...yes i got that ...but whats the alternative to the .offset for an array ...i tried using slice ... but no luck ...

Comment: Ya if you just want to take a slice of the array `start = (page_number.to_i - 1) * per_page;`  `nodes = nodes2.slice(start, per_page)`